# Insertable fields in contacts of salesforce

Tags: soap-api

I cant seem to find any notes regarding this or I might have been barking on the wrong tree. Anyway I know that I can insert to these fields: FirstName, LastName, and email. But how do I insert to the other fields i.e mobile,home phone, billing and shipping address etc, when I can't find what their variables are. this is done via SOAP API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SOAP API, you're looking for [describeSObject()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm), or, for multiple objects, [describeSObjects()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm). It will return a list of fields and their properties, including "createable" and "updateable". These flags honor field level security, so write access is indicated only if the current user actually has permission to do so. Note that some "fields" in salesforce.com are composite fields, such as Mailing Address, which is MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, and MailingCountry. For these specific fields, also take a look at the [SOAP API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/) under "Reference > Standard Objects."